# getting an image url from ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to get an image url, to use that image for further actions in ruby file.

The functionality should be same as following javascript code.

```
var img_src = document.getElementById('elementId').src;
```

Comment: Where are you trying to get the image url from?

Comment: @Frederick Cheung  Iam trying to get image url from header of the same page

Comment: @babu you code example code work just fine then what you exactly you are wanting???

Answer (score 0):

you can try like  this using `Nokogiri` gem

```
page.doc.at_css('#id').attr('src')
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this approach:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125245/getting-an-image-url-from-ruby'
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

p page.css('#feed-link-text a').first.attributes
p page.css('#feed-link-text a').first.attributes.collect{|s|p  s[1].value }
```